# XMPPFramework - Presence not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm trying to set the users presence to away (or anything at the moment). I'm using the following code but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
NSXMLElement *show = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"show" stringValue:@"away"];

NSXMLElement *status = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"status" stringValue:@"away"];
[presence addChild:show];
[presence addChild:status];
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
```

I've used iChat to make sure all the presence subscriptions on my Ejabberd server are correct and working. This is driving me crazy, am I missing something?

Comment: I've never used XMPPFramework, but are you able to get XML logs? That would at least tell you whether you should be debugging the client or server side.

Comment: well that bit of code outputs the following to the console <presence><show>away</show><status>away</status></presence> so it appears to be in the correct format right? Other things being sent using presence (i.e add/remove users etc) seem to work ok. I'll investigate the server side!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out the presence wasn't being sent out by the app as I'd missed this out:

```
- (MMApplication *)appDelegate {
    return (MMApplication *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
- (XMPPStream *)xmppStream {
    return [[self appDelegate] xmppStream];
}
```

Works perfectly now